# How to setup Loggly with Tomcat 8 on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8, loggly

How do I configure Loggly to work with elastic beanstalk and Tomcat 8?

The default script provided by Loggly to setup logging with Tomcat doesn't work because I get the error `cannot find startup.sh`
I set `CATALINA_HOME` as `/usr/share/tomcat8` but there is no .sh scripts that Loggly uses in the `bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works but it will SLOW DOWN everything a lot as it will try to do a POST request each time it makes a log. So it works but I wouldn't recommend to use this.

You can follow the instruction for configuring a normal Java client instead found on `https://yourusername.loggly.com/sources/setup/java_logback`

Add the dependency, for maven it's like so

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.logback-extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-ext-loggly</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Install maven, in IntelliJ this can happen automatically, or simply run
`mvn clean install`

Configure your `logback.xml` file to have the following (if you don't have one you'll need to configure slf4j or something and make one).

You may already have a `<configuration>` or `<root>` tags in place, then just slide in the `<appender>` and `<appender-ref>` lines into the right sections

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="loggly" class="ch.qos.logback.ext.loggly.LogglyAppender">
        <endpointUrl>http://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/d1ad1d1f-7c77-449f-a541-bc56bd6af230/tag/logback</endpointUrl>
        <pattern>%d{"ISO8601", UTC}  %p %t %c{0}.%M - %m%n</pattern>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="loggly" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```